# Passing error message from controller to thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I dont know how to pass an error to thymeleaf outside a form and not specific to a field. Just a small check if the book is on stock. If yes, process everything. If not, throw a error message on the client side.

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping("/books/borrow/{id}")
    public String borrowBook(@PathVariable int id, Errors errors) {

        Book borrowedBook = bookRepository.findById(id);

        if (borrowedBook.getAvailableCount() == 0){
            errors.rejectValue("onStock", "Book out of stock. Come later...");
            return "redirect:/books/";
        } else{...}
```

**View**

```
<p th:text="${onStock}"></p>
```

I don't undestand how to pass the parameter and show it to the client. I did research https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#validation-and-error-messages
but they are all specific to a form and field.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a RedirectAttribute to achieve that:

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping("/books/borrow/{id}")
    public String borrowBook(@PathVariable int id, Errors errors, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    Book borrowedBook = bookRepository.findById(id);

    if (borrowedBook.getAvailableCount() == 0){
        errors.rejectValue("onStock", "Book out of stock. Come later...");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errorMessage", "We couldn't process your order!");
        return "redirect:/books/borrow/" + id;
    } else {
        //Process the request
    }
```

**Template (HTML)**

```
<div th:if="${errorMessage}">
    <div th:text="${errorMessage}"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not work. The user is first at /books/ and when i redirect to this page with the errorMessage. Nothing happens..

Comment: Can you paste the code of your controller and HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

```
    @PostMapping("/books/borrow/{id}")
    public String borrowBook(@PathVariable int id, Errors errors) {

        Book borrowedBook = bookRepository.findById(id);

        if (borrowedBook.getAvailableCount() == 0){
            errors.rejectValue("onStock", "Book out of stock. Come later...");
            return "redirect:/books/?errors="+errors.getAllErrors();
        }
```

on get request mapping

```
@GetMapping("/books")
public String getBooks(Model model, @RequestParam("errors") List<ObjectError> errors) 
{
    model.addAttribute("errors", errors);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: **Required List parameter 'errors' is not present
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required List parameter 'errors' is not present**

I tried to put @Nullable infront of List at the controller but it still does not show the error message afterwards when i test it.

Comment: if you have single error message you can string instead of List<ObjectError>